# Polymer serve refuses external connections

Tags: linux, networking, polymer, polymer-2.x, polymer-cli

I can connect to my server on port 8081 no problem: if I do `nc -l 8081` on my server, and `nc my.host.name 8081` on my local machine, I can send and receive everything perfectly. But if I do `polymer serve` on my server, doing `nc my.host.name 8081` on my local exits immediately, while `nc localhost 8081` works just fine and I can see my index.html served to me if I fake an HTTP request. `nc my.host.name 8081` also fails on the server.

What am I doing wrong? Why is polymer serve only listening to internal requests?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So apparently `polymer serve` only responds to requests made to `localhost` by default. Apparently there's a difference between localhost:8081 and the port 8081 that the rest of the world sees.

You can do `polymer serve -H [external ip]`, where you get that external ip from `ifconfig` where it says `inet addr:`. Alternatively, I seem to be able to do `` polymer serve -H `hostname` `` though I'm not 100% sure that's a general solution.